How to implement hierarchical clustering in Python with scikit-learn for unlabeled data?
I'm learning clustering and had some problems trying to find databases with data
labeled to work with, this was a limitation for me because I found very interesting unlabeled data sets. I have read about various unsupervised clustering techniques and would like to implement hierarchical clustering.
I loaded my data into a pandas DataFrame, standardized the data and applied hierarchical clustering. Then I visualized the dendrogram but I'm not sure how to interpret the results or if I'm using the right parameters.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you're just learning clustering you should start with some of the built in datasets like those found here. They are already labeled for you. Without knowing what your dataset, code, or dendrogram look like, I'm not sure how I can help, but I would definitely recommend you start with the documentation on hierarchical clustering. It sounds like you could potentially benefit through working through a few examples before diving into an unlabeled dataset. Here is an example of hierarchical clustering with unsupervised dimensionality reduction. Here is an example of generating a dendrogram, and here is the Wikipedia page on hierarchical clustering that goes into more detail on the theory behind how dendrograms work. It should help you read dendrograms more easily.
Once you have a firm understanding of the modeling techniques and visualization, you might choose to have some dataset you're interested in labeled if you find it still presents a compelling research question.
Best of luck!

You can use validation techniques such as Silhouette Score, Calinski-Harabasz Index, or Davies-Bouldin Index to know the correctness of model and change the parameters according.
Hope this work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
